# What does having a white dot in the handle of a VS Code tab mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vite

There is a white dot in the head of my vite.config file-tab in vs code. I can't close the tab whatever I do. What is the explanation for this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say you can't you close the tab? Do you get a popup message? If so, what _exactly_ does that popup message say?

Comment: either something weird is going on on your end, or you really should have been able to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 8):

The white dot means that there are changes in the file that haven't been saved. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save your changes and the dot should disappear.

Answer (score -2):

The white dot means there are unsaved changes- that what is currently shown in the editor tab in VS Code is [not yet written to the filesystem, and only exists in the VS Code process' memory](/q/76984829/11107541).

Save the file and then you will be able to close it.

You can use keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on Windows and Linux, and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on macOS). Or use the menu bar's `File > Save` item, or use the `File: Save` command in the command palette.

If you try to close the editor tab while there are unsaved changes (or more precisely, the last editor tab for that file, since you can have multiple editor tabs open for the same file), you'll get a popup that says something to the effect of "Do you want to save the changes you made to <filename>? Your changes will be lost if you don't save them". And from that popup, you should be able to select from the following options: "Don't Save", "Cancel", "Save".

So seeing that you tried to close the file, I'm quite perplexed as to how you didn't figure this out on your own... Unless you *didn't* get that popup for some reason, in which case something might be messed up with your VS Code installation. Or maybe you have an extension messing with VS Code's builtin functionality, in which case you can do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to see if that's the case, and what extension could be causing it.